# Importing Multiple HTML Files Into Excel as Separate Worksheets

Tags: python, html, excel, python-3.x, win32com

I have a number of HTML files that I need to open up or import into a single Excel Workbook and simply save the Workbook. Each HTML file should be on its own Worksheet inside the Workbook.

My existing code does not work and it crashes on the `workbook.Open(html)` line and probably will on following lines. I can't find anything searching the web specific to this topic.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pathlib as path


def save_html_files_to_worksheets(read_directory):
    read_path = path.Path(read_directory)
    save_path = read_path.joinpath('Single_Workbook_Containing_HTML_Files.xlsx')

    excel_app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Add()  # create a new excel workbook

    indx = 1  # used to add new worksheets dependent on number of html files
    for html in read_path.glob('*.html'):  # loop through directory getting html files
        workbook.Open(html)  # open the html in the newly created workbook - this doesn't work though
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(indx)  # each iteration in loop add new worksheet
        worksheet.Name = 'Test' + str(indx)  # name added worksheets
        indx += 1
    workbook.SaveAs(str(save_path), 51)  # win32com requires string like path, 51 is xlsx extension
    excel_app.Application.Quit()


save_html_files_to_worksheets(r'C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\HTML_FOLDER')
```

The following code does half of want I want, if this helps. It will convert each HTML file into a separate Excel file. I need each HTML file in one Excel file with multiple WorkSheets.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pathlib as path

def save_as_xlsx(read_directory):
    read_path = path.Path(read_directory)
    excel_app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

    for html in read_path.glob('*.html'):
        save_path = read_path.joinpath(html.stem + '.xlsx')
        wb = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(html)
        wb.SaveAs(str(save_path), 51)
    excel_app.Application.Quit()


save_as_xlsx(r'C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\HTML_FOLDER')
```

Here is a link to a sample HTML file you can use, the data in the file is not real: [HTML Download Link](https://filebin.net/1i9ke8hs7dkgf77b)

Comment: How should the HTML be inserted? As a raw string into one of the cells? As the contents of a web browser ActiveX control? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The HTML files should be inserted as if you started Excel and opened the HTML files within the application. Each HTML file is essentially a table and they have simple formatting like column widths and font colors that I need to retain.

Comment: How do you open it? An attempt to open an HTML file in Excel 2016 causes an error stating that the file is likely corrupt.

Comment: I added a link at the very bottom of my  original post where you can go and download a sample HTML file. After it has been downloaded, start the Excel application and go to File and Open, then browse for the downloaded HTML file.

Comment: Great, thanks, that one works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to open the HTML file into a temporary workbook, and copy the sheet from there into the workbook containing all of them:

```
workbook = excel_app.Application.Workbooks.Add()
sheet = workbook.Sheets(1)
for path in read_path.glob('*.html'):
    workbook_tmp = excel_app.Application.Workbooks.Open(path)
    workbook_tmp.Sheets(1).Copy(Before=sheet)
    workbook_tmp.Close()
# Remove the redundant 'Sheet1'
excel_app.Application.ShowAlerts = False    
sheet.Delete()
excel_app.Application.ShowAlerts = True
```

Comment: I like your approach and I attempted this before posting, but I couldn't figure it out. It seems like you are missing some stuff. For example, `xl.Application.ShowAlerts = False` and `xl.Application.ShowAlerts = True` `xl` is not defined anywhere. I think you meant to put `excel_app`. Will you please provide the entire code base? I see you are copying it but how do you add it to the other workbook?

Comment: Yep, sorry, `xl` should have been `excel_app`. Other than that, it's the entire thing; `sheet` belongs to the "big" workbook, so by copying the opened HTML file to "the sheet before `sheet`", it will end up in the right place.

Comment: I ran the code and the Excel file that the HTML files are being copied to, is not being saved anywhere. So when I run the code, it appears as if nothing happened. Also, the `excel_app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')` line is missing from your answer.

Comment: `excel_app`, as well as `read_path`, was taken from your original post. Similarly, saving can be handled as in your own post.

Comment: Thanks for the help, let me try and combine what you gave me into my original post and see if I can get this to work.

Comment: Sounds good; if not, let me wrap it up in a convenience function like your own.

Comment: I got it, but because of your expertise. Thank you! I need to do some cleaning up. Default sheet2 and sheet3 still exist to the very right of the copied worksheets in the spreadsheet and need deleted. What do you think the best way of doing that is?

Comment: @jmm5351 Great. So, you start blank workbooks with three sheets? In any case, to delete a sheet by name, you would do `workbook.Worksheets(name).Delete()`, so in your case, where you delete `sheet` towards the end, you could also do `workbook.Worksheets('Sheet2').Delete()` and `workbook.Worksheets('Sheet3').Delete()`.

Comment: To your question, yes excel default is to create three sheets on a blank workbook. Also, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `pandas` will make your job much easier.

`pip install pandas`

Here's an example on how to get multiple tables from a wikipedia html and input it into a Pandas DataFrame and save it to disk.

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_films_of_2017"
wikitables = pd.read_html(url, header=0, attrs={"class":"wikitable"})
for idx,df in enumerate(wikitables):
    df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(idx),index=False)
```

For your use case, something like this should work:

```
import pathlib as path
import pandas as pd

def save_as_xlsx(read_directory):
    read_path = path.Path(read_directory)

    for html in read_path.glob('*.html'):
        save_path = read_path.joinpath(html.stem + '.xlsx')
        dfs_from_html = pd.read_html(html, header=0,)
        for idx, df in enumerate(dfs_from_html):
            df.to_excel('{}.xlsx'.format(idx),index=False)
```

** Make sure to set the correct html attribute in the `pd.read_html` function.

Comment: I don't think pandas data frames will include any formatting. I can't get the `pd.read_html()` to work but I already tested doing this with `pd.read_excel()` and all formatting was lost in the data frame when I saved it to a new excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Using `pd.read_html()`, I get the following Attribute Error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'`

Comment: Thats a little vague, could you post your whole stack trace? `df_from_html` should have the `type` `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. Can you do a `print(type(df_from_html))` and tell me what it says?

Comment: Even if I get this to work, I am almost certain it will not retain the formatting I require in the data frame. Unless you know the data frame will keep font color which is the most important to me. I tested this though using an excel data frame and copied it to another excel spreadsheet and the data frame did NOT keep the formatting.

Comment: Here is the stack trace you requested: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/<UserName>/Documents/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/html_to_excel.py", line 69, in <module>
    save_as_xlsx(r'C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\HTML_FOLDER')
  File "C:/Users/<UserName>/Documents/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/html_to_excel.py", line 67, in save_as_xlsx
    df_from_html.to_excel(str(save_path), index=False)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'`

Comment: Can you print your `save_path`? Try replacing the `df_from_html.to_excel(str(save_path), index=False)  ` line to `df_from_html.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False) `

Comment: To answer your previous question I printed what you asked and it is `Type of "df_from_html" <class 'list'>`. This may be because I omitted the attributes setting that you said I need to include, but I don't know what to include there... I also see others not using the attributes setting and it works still.

Comment: Will the data frame keep formatting? For example, text color.

Comment: No, Pandas will not keep the color or text style formatting.
As for the attribute setting, its okay to skip it as long as your HTML has `<table></table>` within it. If `df_from_html ` is of type `<class 'list'>`, then it contains more than one table. You could iterate over it and write it to file. I've updated the answer with the iteration step.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
Sub From_XML_To_XL()
'UpdatebyKutoolsforExcel20151214
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xSWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xSWb = ThisWorkbook
    xCount = 1
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
        xWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(xCount, 1)
        xWb.Close False
        xCount = xSWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    xSWb.Save
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files xml", , "Kutools for Excel"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer to do this in Python and not with a VBA Macro.